# Authentication error while implementing Stripe in Node js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe in my backend which is in node js. While calling it from front end I am getting this error:

> You did not provide an API key, though you did set your Authorization header to "null". Using Bearer auth, your Authorization header should look something like 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'. See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.

Here is my code:

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.keySecret);

if(req.body.type == 'stripe') {
        const token = req.body.token;
        const amount = req.body.amount;
        let charge = stripe.charges.create({
            amount: amount,
            source: token,
            currency: 'USD'
        },(err, chargeData) => {
            if(err) {
              console.log('error in buy premium api error... ', err);
              return;
            }
            let payment = [];
            payment.push({
              amount: chargeData.amount,
              address: chargeData.billing_details.address,
              email: chargeData.billing_details.email,
              payment_method_details: chargeData.payment_method_details.card
            })
            console.log('charge... ', charge);
            if(charge) {
              register.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: therapist._id }, 
                {
                  $set:
                  {
                    payment_details: payment
                  }
                }, {new:true}, (e1, updatedUser) => {
                if(e1) {
                  return;
                }
  
                resolve(updatedUser);
              })
            }
        })
      }
      else {
        let err = 'No payment type define..';
        return reject(err);
      }
```

My req.body is:

```
{
"token": "tok_1F2XPBG04BYg8nGtLoWnQwRU", // coming from front end
"amount": "250",
"type":"stripe" 
}
```

The secret key is test secret key which is like `sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

My front end is in Angular 6 and from front end I am passing my test publishable key i.e. `pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`. I am passing proper data to the both front end as well as backend. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Are you sure that ```process.env.keySecret``` contains the security token (the one starting with sk_test_)? In order for this to work you have to create an environment variable called "keySecret".

Comment: Yes.. It is test secret key start with "sk_test_xx" and I made environment variable called "keySecret"

Comment: Hi @JaynaTanawala did you figure this issue out? I'm having a similar problem..

Comment: @YuriyF, yes it was key issue.. I given wrong key..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `.env` file, you have to include the following line before requiring stripe:

```
require ("dotenv").config();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.keySecret);
```